# Using a JWT token with dropwizard? I already have db auth, but am confused about utilizing tokens

Tags: java, rest, authentication, jwt, dropwizard

I have the following Authenticator class for DB authentication:

```
public class DBAuthentication implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, User> {

    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public DBAuthentication(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException{
       return userDAO.findByUsernamePassword(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
    }
}
```

and then when I want to authenticate against a resource, I simply do :

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/secured")
@UnitOfWork
public String aliveSecure(@Auth User user)
{
    return "working.";
}
```

Which is a simple, authenticated method - and that works well... However, let's assume I want to have a user sign in, then get a token they can use for future requests, until the token expires... I would ASSUME (and correct me if I am wrong) that I would do something like have a resource, which would take the credentials, then return the token inside a response, for storage on the client end - and that is fine... but if I do that, how would I later authenticate against the token?

Comment: Looks like maybe dropwizard doesn't support this behavior? I can't find anything useful on the topic online, and nobody seems to have commented here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct -- You will add an endpoint which issues JWT tokens once authenticated, and then annotate your other protected resources to use JWT authentication.

Check out [dropwizard-auth-jwt](https://github.com/ToastShaman/dropwizard-auth-jwt), which adds JWT support to Dropwizard. There is an example on how to use it in their [examples directory on Github](https://github.com/ToastShaman/dropwizard-auth-jwt/tree/master/src/test/java/com/github/toastshaman/dropwizard/auth/jwt/example).

Specifically look at the [SecuredResource](https://github.com/ToastShaman/dropwizard-auth-jwt/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/toastshaman/dropwizard/auth/jwt/example/SecuredResource.java) class, which can both issue a token as well as validate it.

You can for instance just extend your `aliveSecure` method to issue a JWT token.

I made an [example project available at on Github](https://github.com/hendrikvh/dropwizard-jwt-demo) which uses basic auth to issue tokens, and `@Roles` with JWTs.

Comment: Ah, cool - so then what happens if I need this to work with roles? My plan was to add a simple auth filter, verify my JWT in there, and somehow use the "@RolesAllowed" annotation with that jwt to allow the use to use certain endpoints? Is that something that can be done? I can't seem to find an example of this anywhere which actually does this? It seems like if I want to authenticate with a token like this, I have to lose all of the "@RolesAllowed" functionality?

Comment: No, you can use the RolesAllowed annotation still. I will see if I can upload an example to Github later if you hang on a bit.

Comment: That would be SO helpful - the rest of the dropwizard stuff I see, I totally get - but the auth stuff has me baffled beyond belief (I had db auth working no problem, but getting tokens, and roles etc working, is so weird)

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds I added an example project. See the answer above.

Comment: Tnankyou - I wont get to look at the example for another day or two - but I will mark this as best answer anyway, you have been so helpful!

Comment: I am having a slight problem when trying to follow your example...

On this line of code : 

        final AbstractBinder binder = new PolymorphicAuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(
                ImmutableSet.of(PrincipalImpl.class, User.class));

I get the error : "Cannot inver arguments" - and the "<>" is underlined in red... am I missing something?

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds Open an issue on that repo and we can take it from there to resolve it.